# Pre 1794 records for Rothenditmold, Kassel, Hessen, Germany?

Tags: germany, 18th-century, vital-records, hesse

I've been using [Archion](https://www.archion.de/de/browse/?path=177273-305273-306749) and have found a lot of records for my family there. But the archive stops at 1794. I've also use [lagis-hessen](http://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/gsearch/sn/pstr?q=Rothenditmold&submit=LAGIS-Suche) though those records don't go as far back as Archion.

Are there any other digital archives I can search in an attempt to find earlier records for Rothenditmold, Kassel, Hessen, Germany?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am no export on Hesse, but I did a little research:

Your LAGIS results are *civil* registration which started in 1874.

Church records for several parishes in today’s city of Kassel were destroyed during World War II, according to a text from 1954 at the local history site [*Erinnerungen im Netz, Erlebtes aus dem Osten Kassels*](http://www.erinnerungen-im-netz.de/aw/Testseiten/~zz/Die_Geschichte_der_Bettenhaeuser_Kirchenbuecher/). They name: Waldau, Nieder-und Oberzwehren, Nordshausen und Wolfsanger, ***and partly*** Wahlershausen, Wehlheiden, Harleshausen, Kirch- und Rothenditmold.

The German genealogy wiki *GenWiki* says however, that the following parish records are on microfilm in the state archive (*Hessisches Staatsarchiv Marburg*):

- Kirchditmold, Harleshausen, Rothenditmold, Wahlershausen, Wehlheiden, Weißenstein 1624-1753

I could not trace these records using https://arcinsys.hessen.de/arcinsys

A user on the Archion message board [complains](https://www.archion.de/de/forum/?tx_mmforum_pi1%5Btopic%5D=1358&tx_mmforum_pi1%5BshowForm%5D=0&tx_mmforum_pi1%5Baction%5D=show&tx_mmforum_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=Topic&cHash=38a1607591a2df0c8cb84600245cd698), that helpful notes are missing on the platform, e.g. "that Rothenditmold belonged to Kirchditmold before 1794". [Kirchditmold is available on Archion](https://www.archion.de/de/browse/#https://www.archion.de/de/browse/&path=177273-305273-306122), I see however no records between 1754 and 1830.

There is a self-published book by Herbert Lamprecht: *Harleshausen und Rothenditmold: Kirchenbuch: 1773 - 1830* from 1998. I assume it is some structured collection of transcribed data, maybe by family name. The church archive in Kassel seems to be the only place where this is [publicly available](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/item/NT4CLCPYBBCCHGJLMULI6G3ZAU67IUNK) right now (no scans, however).

This book however indicates, that Rothenditmold might have belonged to Harleshausen, [the period between 1773 and 1830 is covered on Archion under *Harleshausen*](https://www.archion.de/de/browse/#https://www.archion.de/de/browse/&path=177273-305273-306005).

GenWiki also [lists](http://wiki-de.genealogy.net/Hessische_Kirchenbuchbearbeitungen#Regierungsbezirk_Kassel) another two books of compiled church book data:

- BREDE, Herta; LAMPRECHT, Herbert (1998) Kirchenbuch Kassel-Weißenstein 1624-1702. Schauenburg-Hoof/Fuldatal-Simmershausen: Brede/Lamprecht, 518 S., Register [GFKW]
- BREDE, Herta; LAMPRECHT, Herbert (1998) Kirchenbuch Kassel-Weißenstein 1703-1753. Schauenburg-Hoof/Fuldatal-Simmershausen: Brede/Lamprecht, 483 S., Register [GFKW]

Here it says "Weißenstein (enth. Kirchditmold, Rothenditmold, Wahlershausen, Wehlheiden, Harleshausen)", meaning that all the parishes are contained in the records of Weißenstein for this period. There are no matching records on Archion right now.

From the book titles *I’d assume* that Kirchditmold belonged to Weißenstein from 1624 to 1753 and later to Harleshausen, before it became a separate parish. As I don't know this for sure, I would recommend to contact the local genealogy society *[Gesellschaft für Familienkunde in Kurhessen und Waldeck e.V.](http://www.gfkw.de/)* and ask how to proceed. They have also a mailing list, other bulletin boards with a subsection for Hesse are

- [Hessen - forum.genealogy.net](http://forum.genealogy.net/index.php?page=Board&boardID=43&s=852eb3ae29dda98793733303d41fbc43528a90de)
- [Hessen Genealogie - forum.ahnenforschung.net](http://forum.ahnenforschung.net/forumdisplay.php?f=28)

They should be fine with questions in English.

You should also check the records mentioned above on Archion, if they indicate coverage for other parishes or if you even find individuals from your research there (e.g. a birth entry when the age and thus the year is known from a marriage entry).

Comment: Kirchenbuch Harleshausen und Rothenditmold is now available online, thanks to the Universität Kassel: https://orka.bibliothek.uni-kassel.de/viewer/!image/1666096539210/1/-/

Comment: Two others that were recently added also may be of assistance:
Kirchenbuch Kassel-Weißenstein

https://orka.bibliothek.uni-kassel.de/viewer/toc/1666097125157/1/

 
Kasseler Einwohnerlisten des 17. Jahrhunderts

https://orka.bibliothek.uni-kassel.de/viewer/image/1666175507985/1/